# Git: Testing a branch against master locally?

Tags: git

So I have a branch for automated tests that i've written for a Rails app, the branch basically consists of all the .rb spec files (the tests themselves) and a few other things.

I also have the master branch.

These are the only 2 branches I have locally. So when I switch to the automation branch, I can only see the files im working on (the automated tests) but if switch back to master....they go away (Which makes sense, because they aren't merged).

However if I want to test them against master, i'd need to have all the files together? Is there any way I can do this? Im quite new to Git.

Comment: If by testing you mean seeing the differences then use: git diff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is

1. Create a new branch out of your master

   `git checkout master`

   `git checkout -b new_branch`
2. Merge your test branch into new branch

   `git merge test_branch`

Now your new_branch will have all the code of both the branches.
This way you can keep your other two branches intact and test your app on `new_branch`

Comment: This is a great idea! thanks. I guess to me im not used to making branches for everything so it seems odd

Comment: As git is distributed Version Control system you can create as many branches on your local machine as you want that's how people and i work

let's say i'm working on x feature i'll create branch x from master and work on feature branch until i feel it's ok to merge it back into master

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create a new branch and merge it just for this testing effort (and maybe later delete that branch to clean up), you can simply grab those files from your master branch while on your other branch by doing a `git checkout master -- <fileList>`